# Custom Channel Grouping

Tags: looker-studio

Used this code to create a custom channel grouping but it includes an extra dimension that is not named but has data valued on the time series

I have tried to edit the code and reenter it but the extra dimension still remains and because it is not named I cannot figure out how to eliminate it

```
CASE 
WHEN ((Source="direct" AND Medium="(not set)") OR Medium="(none)") THEN "Direct" 
WHEN Medium="organic" THEN "Organic Search" 
WHEN Medium="referral" THEN "Referral" 
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Medium,"^(cpc|ppc|paidsearch)$") AND Ad Distribution Network!="Content" THEN "Paid Search" 
END
```

I expect to see Direct, Organic search, referral and Paid search as the only data values on my time series but I have all those appear and then another set of data values show up on the time series and in the legend but this dimension is unnamed and I am not sure where the code is wrong

Comment: Hi, you can format text as a code with 3 symbols " ` " at the beginning of the code  and 3 " ` ".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're getting the extra dimension but you could add the else statement below and then use a filter to remove the "Delete" dimension

```
CASE 
WHEN ((Source="direct" AND Medium="(not set)") OR Medium="(none)") THEN "Direct" 
WHEN Medium="organic" THEN "Organic Search" 
WHEN Medium="referral" THEN "Referral" 
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Medium,"^(cpc|ppc|paidsearch)$") AND Ad Distribution Network!="Content" 
THEN "Paid Search" 
ELSE "Delete"
END
```

Comment: How do you filter out the delete dimension?

Comment: Create you graph how you want it (with the dimension you don't want). Select the graph in edit mode and on the right panel it will have "Data" and "Style" options. Select "Data" and towards the bottom of that panel you will see a graph filter option. Click "Create a filter" (might need to do that again on the next screen too). Then create a filter that is "Exclude", your custom dimension, "Equal to", "Delete".

Comment: Note also that if you have an entire page that you need this value excluded on, you can also apply filters under Page > Current page settings > Add a Filter. By default, this will be inherited by all charts and filters on the page, although there's an option to override that inheritance on each chart.

Comment: @CatherineHogan Also, the reason for the extra dimension is that in Data Studio, `CASE` statements don't *filter* data—meaning that omitting an `ELSE` doesn't exclude the unmatched values, it just basically sets them to blank for the type (usually empty string or `0`). So it's best to always have an else so that you control how these are handled (especially if your values could potentially have empty elements already).

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this is showing up as blank because it's traffic that doesn't have a utm tag? That should show up as (not set) but you never know. If you pull the channel into a table along with full referrer, is there anything distinguishing the blank ones from the others, so you know how to categorize it, then you can add anything blank to a specific channel?